# Decode unknown string

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, chardet

I have one source of data, that I don't control, and that sends strings with different encodings, and I have no way to know the encoding in advance! I would need to know the format to be able to correctly decode and store properly in a format that I understand and control, let's say UTF-8.

for example:

- "J'ai dÃ©jÃ\xa0 un problÃ¨me, aprÃ¨s... je ne sais pas"

should read

- "J'ai déjà un problème, après... je ne sais pas"

**What I have tried:**

```
> stringToTest="J'ai dÃ©jÃ\xa0 un problÃ¨me, aprÃ¨s... je ne sais pas"
# there is no decode for string, directly, but one can try
> stringToTest.encode().decode()
"J'ai dÃ©jÃ\xa0 un problÃ¨me, aprÃ¨s... je ne sais pas"
# what does not help :)
```

From trial and error, I found that the encoding is 'iso-8859-1'

```
> stringToTest.encode('iso-8859-1').decode()
"J'ai déjà un problème, après... je ne sais pas"
```

**What I want/need is to find the 'iso-8859-1' automatically!**

I tried to use chardet!

```
> import chardet

> chardet.detect(stringToTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/188/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/chardet/__init__.py", line 34, in detect
    '{0}'.format(type(byte_str)))
TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'str'>
```

But... as it is a string... chardet does not accept it!
And, I am ashamed to admit, but I don't manage to convert the string into something that chardet accepts!

```
> test1=b"J'ai dÃ©jÃ un problÃ¨me, aprÃ¨s... je ne sais pas"
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.

# Ok str and unicode are similar things... but who knows?!?!
> test1=u"J'ai dÃ©jÃ un problÃ¨me, aprÃ¨s... je ne sais pas"
> chardet.detect(test1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/188/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/chardet/__init__.py", line 34, in detect
    '{0}'.format(type(byte_str)))
TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'str'>

# NOP
> bytes(stringToTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/188/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Why not unidecode?!?

```
from unidecode import unidecode

from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(stringToTest)
'J\'ai dA(c)jA un problA"me, aprA"s... je ne sais pas'
```

Comment: _I have one source of data, that I don't control, and that sends strings with different encodings_ You receive the data as Python strings directly?

Comment: I am REALLY sorry for the delay, I kind off got out of the circulation :(. I receive a json file, from different sources, all around of the word and they send on their own encoding. It is like a rest service, if you wish.

Comment: _I receive a json file_ How? How are you reading/parsing it?

Comment: I receive it in a file, a dump if you wish. But each one of these files came from a different source. I just open the file, for example:  DAM!!!!! You are RIGHT I AM STUPID!!!!!!!!!  I am really sorry!!! I am opening with "with open(fullFileName, encoding="utf8") as json_data:" THAT maybe why!!! I will make some more tests!

Answer (score 1):

The string

```
"J'ai dÃ©jÃ\xa0 un problÃ¨me, aprÃ¨s... je ne sais pas"
```

is an example of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) - encoded text (`bytes`) which has been decoded with the wrong encoding.  In this particular case, the string was originally encoded as UTF-8; re-encoding as ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) recreates the UTF-8 bytes, and decoding from UTF-8 (the default in Python3) produces the expected result.

If you are receiving these *mojibake* strings from an external source, you can safely encode them using  ISO-8859-1 to recreate the original bytes.  The bytes - *encoded text* - may be passed to `chardet` for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the same, I am really sorry for the long delay in returning to you. The thing is that in this particular case it is  ISO-8859-1, and I got that by trial and error, but I have no guarantees that the next string that will arrive will not arrive in  another XXX encoding that I don't know off. I understand it works like that, stringToTest.encode('XXX').decode()== "a clean utf8 string". But how to find "XXX" automatically? I don't know, I may be going the wrong way and the answer is clear to all, but me! :(

Comment: @DanielCamara Can you provide some more context for this? How exactly do you receive the data?